# Limited resolution in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VirtualBox and i have this problem.
My Resolution is locked to maximum 1280x720 (4:2) and my windows host OS is running on 1920x1080 (16:9) Widescreen. Do i need to install some special drivers for VirtualBox or update Ubuntu?

---

Specs:
ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series

Intel Core 2 Quad Core CPU Q9300 @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.5GHz

6GB RAM

---

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install VirtualBox Guest Additions, depending of VirtualBox version you use.
Refer to the official website for downloading.

Comment: can you please provide a link for the Guest Additions. I can't find them. Thanks.

Comment: @K1ll3rbyt3: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox